# How to add character at the end of specific line in UNIX/LINUX?

Tags: linux, unix, addition, seq

Here is my input file. I want to add a character ":" into the end of lines that have ">" at the beginning of the line. I tried `seq -i 's|$|:|' input.txt` but ":" was added to all the ending of each line. It is also hard to call out specific line numbers because, in each of my input files, the line contains">" present in different line numbers. I want to run a loop for multiple files so it is useless.

```
>Pas_pyrG_2
AAAGTCACAATGGTTAAAATGGATCCTTATATTAATGTCGATCCAGGGACAATGAGCCCA
TTCCAGCATGGTGAAGTTTTTGTTACCGAAGATGGTGCAGAAACAGATCTGGATCTGGGT
>Pas_rpoB_4
CAAACTCACTATGGTCGTGTTTGTCCAATTGAAACTCCTGAAGGTCCAAACATTGGTTTG
ATCAACTCGCTTTCTGTATACGCAAAAGCGAATGACTTCGGTTTCTTGGAAACTCCATAC
CGCAAAGTTGTAGATGGTCGTGTAACTGATGATGTTGAATATTTATCTGCAATTGAAGAA
>Pas_cpn60_2
ATGAACCCAATGGATTTAAAACGCGGTATCGACATTGCAGTAAAAACTGTAGTTGAAAAT
ATCCGTTCTATTGCTAAACCAGCTGATGATTTCAAAGCAATTGAACAAGTAGGTTCAATC
TCTGCTAACTCTGATACTACTGTTGGTAAACTTATTGCTCAAGCAATGGAAAAAGTAGGT
AAAGAAGGCGTAATCACTGTAGAAGAAGGCTCAGGCTTCGAAGACGCATTAGACGTTGTA
```

Here is experted output file:

```
    >Pas_pyrG_2:
    AAAGTCACAATGGTTAAAATGGATCCTTATATTAATGTCGATCCAGGGACAATGAGCCCA
    TTCCAGCATGGTGAAGTTTTTGTTACCGAAGATGGTGCAGAAACAGATCTGGATCTGGGT
    >Pas_rpoB_4:
    CAAACTCACTATGGTCGTGTTTGTCCAATTGAAACTCCTGAAGGTCCAAACATTGGTTTG
    ATCAACTCGCTTTCTGTATACGCAAAAGCGAATGACTTCGGTTTCTTGGAAACTCCATAC
    CGCAAAGTTGTAGATGGTCGTGTAACTGATGATGTTGAATATTTATCTGCAATTGAAGAA
    >Pas_cpn60_2:
    ATGAACCCAATGGATTTAAAACGCGGTATCGACATTGCAGTAAAAACTGTAGTTGAAAAT
    ATCCGTTCTATTGCTAAACCAGCTGATGATTTCAAAGCAATTGAACAAGTAGGTTCAATC
    TCTGCTAACTCTGATACTACTGTTGGTAAACTTATTGCTCAAGCAATGGAAAAAGTAGGT
    AAAGAAGGCGTAATCACTGTAGAAGAAGGCTCAGGCTTCGAAGACGCATTAGACGTTGTA
```

Do `seq` have more option to modify or the other commands can solve this problem?

Comment: `seq`? the program that writes out a sequence of numbers?  Surely you mean `sed` the stream editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i  '/^>/ s/$/:/' input.txt
```

Search the lines of input for lines that match `^>` (regex for "starts with the `>` character).  Those that do *s*ubstitute `:` for end-of-line (you got this part right).

`/` slashes are the standard separator character in `sed`.  If you wish to use different characters, be sure to pass `-e` or `s|$|:|` probably won't work.  Since `/` characters, unlike `|` characters, are not meaningful character within the shell, it's best to use them unless the pattern also contains slashes, in which case things get unwieldy.

Be careful with `sed -i`.  Make a backup  - make sure you know what's changing by using `diff` to compare the files.

On OSX `-i` requires an argument.

Comment: It worked thank you so much. I want to ask 1 more question that here I wanna remove all characters to the left of "-".  I tried by count the characters but the number of characters from each line is different :( 
Here is input 
rplB_2-CGTCGTTATATCATTGCGCCTAAAGGCT  \n

rpoB_4-CAAACTCACTATGGTCGTGTTTGTCCA
The expected output is:
CGTCGTTATATCATTGCGCCTAAAGGCT \n

CAAACTCACTATGGTCGTGTTTGTCCAA

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` to edit the file:

```
printf "%s\n" 'g/^>/s/$/:/' w | ed -s input.txt
```

For every line starting with `>`, add a colon to the end, and then **w**rite the changed file back to disk.